# En Javascript. Donde se pasan los valores por defecto en una clase hija ( extends). En "super" o en el "constructor"

Tags: javascript, funciones, diseño-de-clases, clase-anidada, class

Donde deben colocarse los valores por defecto de los argumentos pasados de la superclase (Vehículo) a la clase hija (bicicleta):

```
class Bicicleta extends Vehiculo {
   constructor({numeroDeRuedas=2, tieneMotor=false}={}){
      super(numeroDeRuedas, tieneMotor);
```

o así:

```
class Bicicleta extends Vehiculo {
    constructor(numeroDeRuedas, tieneMotor){
        super({numeroDeRuedas=2, tieneMotor=false}={});
```

o así:

```
class Bicicleta extends Vehiculo {
    constructor({numeroDeRuedas=2, tieneMotor=false}={}){
        super({numeroDeRuedas=2, tieneMotor=false}={});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
class vehiculo {
  constructor(b){
   this.method = b;  
  }
}

class ford extends vehiculo {
  constructor(c){ // recibe el parametro de new ford()
  super("Este parametro es para el padre");  // llamo al padre  
  this.g = c;  
  }
}

var child = new ford("this.g de la clase child"), father = new vehiculo();

console.log(child.g); // se lo pasamos en la variable child
console.log(child.method); // se lo pasamos al padre en super(), pero child lo hereda

console.log(father.method); /* esta es otra instancia, entonces el method
                               está sin definir.
*/
console.log(new vehiculo("Ahora esta definido").method) // ahora si lo definimos
```